# How to Display Two ArrayList values in Android ListView?

Tags: android

```
package com.in2em.hotel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint("ParserError")
```

Activity to display two arraylist in listview

```
  public class OrderActivity extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<String> data,rate;
    OrderAdapter orderAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.order);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        data = extras.getStringArrayList("list");
        rate = extras.getStringArrayList("rate");
        for(String str : data)  {
            Log.d("data", str);

        }
        for(String str1 : rate) {
            Log.d("data", str1);

        }
```

data and rate are two arraylist

```
        String[] captionArray = (String[]) data.toArray(
                new String[data.size()]);
        String[] rateArray = (String[]) rate.toArray(
                new String[rate.size()]);
        R.layout.order_list,R.id.itemname, captionArray));
```

How to set the two array list in listview ? I can set only one arraylist ?

```
     orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(
                OrderActivity.this, R.layout.order_list,
                captionArray);
```

setting the list adapter

```
        setListAdapter(orderAdapter);

        return ;
    }
```

Custum listAdapter

```
         private class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] items;

        public OrderAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] items) {
            this.items = items;
        }
```

Returning the views

```
        public View getView(final int POSITION, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView tvNumber,tvName,tvRate;
            EditText etQty,etRemarks;

            View view = convertView;
```

Inflate

```
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = vi.inflate(R.layout.order_list, null);

            } 
                tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemname);
            tvRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemrate);

            tvName.setText(data.get(POSITION));
            tvRate.setText(rate.get(POSITION));


            return view; 
        }


        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return items.length;
        }


        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }


        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a third one created from these two ArrayList.

Comment: Add contents of the two arraylists to a third one and use the third one in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Change your constructor to accept two ArrayLists and store them within the Adapter:

```
private class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> data;
    ArrayList<String> rate;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> data, ArrayList<String> rate) {
        this.data = data;
        this.rate = rate;
    } 

    // Use the same getView(), for now

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size(); // rate must be the same size as data!
    }

    public String getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
 orderAdapter = new OrderAdapter(this, data, rate);
```

Also you should watch this [Android lecture](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) on adapters and ListViews to speed up `getView()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> secondList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> thirdList;
firstList.add("...");
secondList.add("...");

thirdList = new ArrayList<String>(firstList);
thirdList.addAll(secondList);
```

Apply `thirdList` to your Adapter.